# Python: How to manage rounding behavior between float and int?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, rounding

What is the best way to avoid a rounding problem when doing:

```
>>> a =8.92138 
>>> a
8.92138 
>>> int(a*100000)
892137
```

Decimal gives me

```
>>> Decimal(a)
Decimal('8.921379999999999199644662439823150634765625')
```

Comment: I don't really get the downvote - what's wrong with the question?

Comment: Precision problem? `int` does an integer floor operation. It loses all precision below unity.

Comment: Well, maybe you can better explain than simply downvote.

Comment: You have not really explained what rounding problem you think you are having. Using floating-point arithmetic is implicitly saying “I want to use arithmetic with approximations for results that are not exactly representable.” Converting directly to integer is implicitly saying “I want to convert with hard boundaries at the integers; chop away any fractional parts.” So you are saying contradictory things: Use approximations to stay close to the mathematical answer but discard fractions to move away from the mathematical answer. To resolve this, we need to know what you really want to calculate.

Comment: For example, why are you converting to integer? You had a perfectly reasonable floating-point value; why convert it to integer and discard its fractional part? And why not round it to integer instead of converting it (which uses truncation)?

Comment: I have a string representation of a coordinate, without dimension. I need to calculate some real world distances so they are converted to floats (actually doubles in C). I'm looking for clean way to switch between those two representations.

Comment: @LarsVegas: Given that, simply convert from a float to a string (presumably you mean a string containing a numeral) without using integer at all, and vice-versa.

Comment: Well, but I need to add the dimension (*100000). So you mean I should simply delete the `.`?

Comment: @LarsVegas: Convert from a string to a float. Perform arithmetic, such as multiplying by 100000. Convert from a float to a string. Do not involve integers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` does not round -- it finds the floor (truncates the fractional part).

```
>>> n = 8.92138
>>> '%.42f' % n   # what n really is
'8.921379999999999199644662439823150634765625'
>>> 100000 * n # result is slightly lower than 892138
892137.9999999999
>>> int(100000 * n) # int takes the floor
892137
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Decimal from the beginning if possible:

```
>>> a = Decimal('8.92138')
>>> int(a * 100000)
892138
```

---

To round use [Decimal.quantize](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal#decimal.Decimal.quantize)

```
>>> a = 8.92138
>>> Decimal(a) * 100000
Decimal('892137.9999999999199644662440')
>>> (Decimal(a) * 100000).quantize(1)
Decimal('892138')

>>> str(a)
'8.92138'
>>> int(Decimal(str(a)) * 100000)
892138
```

Comment: We are not talking about a `str` but a `float`. If you do `a = Decimal(8.92138)` you still end up with the same problem.

Comment: @LarsVegas, Using `float`, you can't get exact value. I updated the code.

Comment: @LarsVegas Yes, you do, which is why you shouldn't be using a float in the first place. Once you have a float, it's too late. You can't get back an exact value from an inexact value.

Comment: @LarsVegas, I'm not talking about `str`, neither. ;)

Comment: `Decimal` is not a catch-all answer. You need to know what calculations are going to be performed. `Decimal` is no more exact than binary floating point when there is division by numbers other than powers of ten, when there are various “scientific” functions such as sine or logarithm, et cetera.